# Is this model of memory compatible with NUC?

Tags: hard-drive, ramdisk, intel-nuc

I am curious if the three items in the attached image are compatible and if it's all I need to get an Intel NUC running?

Update:
My plan is to run this on Ubuntu 18 Server LTS or CentOS 7

[image: Shopping Cart Example]

Comment: Yeah they'll all work just fine - what OS are you planning on using, the driver options are a little tight for that model - ESXi 6.x and W10 work fine on them, I struggled with various Linux's though.

Comment: I've used Ubuntu successfully on a 7i7BNH , using a Samsung 860 evo m.2 and similar RAM.  When ordering personal computer parts, it's good to order from a vendor with a return policy or RMA policy (Amazon or Newegg is fine), in case you need to get a different part.